# Pasar valor de componente padre a hijo react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, props

Estoy intentando pasar un valor de un hijo a padre con react, mi problema es que despues de que mando el valor mediante una función como prop, cuando voy a guardarlo en una constante del padre no se guarda.

Componente padre:

```
export default function Padre() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState('')
  const [verify, setVerify] = useState('')

  function pasarToken(t) {
    setToken(t)
    {/*El valor de token aparece vacio pero "t" es correcto*/}
    console.log("Valor traido "+t+" ,valor en padre "+token)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <ThemeProvider theme={mytheme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        { token.length>=6 ? <Perfil token={token}/> : <Login pasarToken={pasarToken}/> }
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  )
}
```

Componente Hijo

```
export default function Login(props) {
  const [token, setToken] = useState('')

  return (
    <div className="login">          
        <Grid item direction="column" spacing={2} className='loginDiv'>              
          <Grid item sm={12}>
            <Button fullWidth="true" variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={()setVerify('valorPrueba');props.pasarToken(token);console.log("login: "+token)}}     >Ingresar</Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  )
}
```

En el padre la función `pasarToken` la variable `t` si contiene el valor pero cuando la guardo con `setToken` aparece como un string vacío, nose si el problema es al guardarlo o al traer el valor?

Comment: No es un problema, de hecho tu estado token tiene el valor; lo que pasa, es que dicho estado estará "disponible" en la prox renderización del componente, debido a la asincronia con la que trabaja React. Considera manejar la actualización de tu estado mediante useEffect. Además, en tu hijo estas llamando al state setVerify, el cual jamás envias por props

Comment: Ya probe con el useEffect y si me funciono, gracias.